# What is the correct way to calculate invoice total comprising rounding?

Tags: c#, rounding

Here is a real world question: if I have a product A with a unit price of $25.8848 and I ordered 77 units of it then how I should calculate the subtotal and total?

I am actually getting confused about rounding issues. The code I have written is this:

```
Math.Round(item.Price, 2) * item.Qty
```

This should give me the correct subtotal and summing the other item will provided me correct total. Is the above code correct in terms of rounding? Or should it be done like this:

```
Math.Round(item.Price * item.Qty, 2)
```

I just want to know how the subtotal price rounding is done in real world.

Comment: Usually the company has rules about that.  Most would round the result, not the price though - it makes storing more than 2 decimals for price pointless.

Comment: Agree with Plutonix. You should only do rounding when display the final result, not at each calculation. Another suggestion, to use "decimal" data type for your Price property to ensure accuracy. Do NOT use "double".

Answer (score 2):

Rounding should be applied per line item so the second method you have posted would be correct.  Each line item subtotal should be rounded. Here is an example of it although it is coded in ruby you can get the idea etc

http://makandracards.com/makandra/1505-invoices-how-to-properly-round-and-calculate-totals

Answer (score 1):

Either way is correct as far as C# is concerned.  This is really a question about your company's accounting and business rules.   Ideally this would be defined in the requirements document when the application was designed.

That being said, I would usually expect the 2nd option to be correct, apply the rounding AFTER the price is multiplied by the quantity.

Comment: just check this post here I guess they are confirming with product price rounding 

https://hotcakescommerce.com/Community/AskaQuestion/tabid/56/cid/3387/Default.aspx